# How to use usort on my particular array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, usort

Just been looking at some examples involving usort and I cant quite get my head around making the function for my array. Im sure it is quite simple, so I thought I would ask on here. I am using twig and redbean but I dont think that is relavant. Here is my code:

```
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
$userfol =  R::find('follow','user_id=?', array($user->id));
foreach ($userfol as $uf)
{
    $userrec = R::find('recipe','user_id=?', array($uf->following_id));
}
```

I want to SORT the array $userrec to display recipes by their date created and I want to limit it to displaying only 1 recipe at a time. Any Ideas?

Thanks very much in advanced.

Comment: I'd think doing this in the database will be a lot more constructive than using `usort`.

Comment: I agree with Deceze. There's no sense in doing it in PHP if it can be done in DB.

Comment: Thanks deceze, how would you propose I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like stated in the comments doing this in the database would be the most efficient. Looking up the documentation for RedBean I found http://redbeanphp.com/manual2_0/finding_beans. Taking from there:

```
$needles = R::find('needle',' haystack = :haystackname 
                              ORDER BY :sortorder', 
array( 'sortorder'=>$sortorder, ':haystack'=>$haystack ));
```

Applying this example to your code above would be done as follows:

```
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
$userfol =  R::find('follow','user_id=? ORDER BY create_date', array($user->id));
foreach ($userfol as $uf)
{
    $userrec = R::find('recipe','user_id=?', array($uf->following_id));
}
```

The above example's sort order is not dynamic, but you can replace it with a question mark just like the user id.

While I'm at it, you can use :name instead of question marks. Question marks are evaluated in the order you put them there, and take the values from the data array in order. When started with a colon it will look for that name in an associative array, which may be favorable.

If for some reason you want to use usort anyway, I set up an example [here](http://ideone.com/tsOsxV). As you can see the sorter function compares the create_date element of $a and $b, you can replace this with something relevant to your application. As for what you should return, to quote from the docs:

> The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, or
>   greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be
>   respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

Comment: Thanks for this, I had seen it before but was not sure how to implement it for my code. Do you have an idea how your example above might look with my code? Sorry for being naive.

Comment: Wow thank you very much for you help @WouterH I will give it a go and get back to you! Very kind.

Comment: @MikeHolford I just looked at your previous questions and gathered from that, that your R::find returns one item because (presumably) user_id is unique. In that case ORDER BY won't help you, and $userrec won't be an array. ORDER BY sorts items returned by that one SQL query (or R::find call, if you prefer to call it that).

You may want to look into SQL joins in that case, but I am not familliar enough with RedBean to offer a suggestion.

Comment: Thanks @WouterH I just tried `$userrec = R::find('recipe','user_id=? ORDER BY uploaddate LIMIT 1', array($uf->following_id));` for the $userrec array and it seems to display correctly! It may be because I am storing the array as follows `$vals['userrec']` so the ORDER BY works. Thank you anyway, very much appreciated. I think if I am joining two database tables though I may need to use your function in the future or usort. Thank you!

Comment: @MikeHolford I'm glad to hear that it works, but I am suprised that it does. ORDER BY should not have any effect when only one item is returned (which you are enforcing with LIMIT 1).